# Changing the Zoom In/Out centerpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, zooming, transformation

I'm writing a WPF application that displays a XAML object (it's basically a map drawn in XAML). As part of its features, it should zoom in/out and pan. The panning works fine, and the zoom zooms, but I can't quite understand how to zoom to a specific point, like my mouse cursor, for example.

This is my current code:

```
internal void PerformZoom(float ZoomFactor, Point ZoomCenterPoint)
{
  m_originalTransform = m_canvas.RenderTransform;
  float newZoomFactor = m_oldZoomFactor + ZoomFactor;

  float scaleToApply = (newZoomFactor / m_oldZoomFactor);
  m_totalZoom = newZoomFactor;

  var st = new ScaleTransform(scaleToApply, scaleToApply);

  TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
  tg.Children.Add(m_originalTransform);
  tg.Children.Add(st);
  m_canvas.RenderTransform = tg;

  m_oldZoomFactor = newZoomFactor;
}
```

**[edit]** Found the solution - Just edited the CenterX / CenterY properties of the transformation and it worked like a charm.
Thanks for all your help!

**[edit2]** Here's a viable solution (considering the mouse position):

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private float currentZoom = 1f;
    private const float StepSize = .2f;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainGrid_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = 1;
        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            pos = -1;
        }

        var mousePosition = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(MainGrid);

        currentZoom += StepSize * pos;
        var transform = new ScaleTransform(currentZoom, currentZoom, mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y);
        MainGrid.RenderTransform = transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not show what you did someone else might find it helpful. I have no idea what *CenterX / CenterY properties of the transformation* you referred to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to compose your ScaleTransform with a TranslateTransform which translates your component while zooming.

The offset given by the TranslateTransform depends of the behavior you wanna have (i.e. center on mouse, center on screens center...)

I wrote in the past a behavior which you can attach to a component : It makes it zoomable (centered on mouse, reacting to mousewheel)
It's pretty dirty and not sure to be efficient (i no longer use it)... and comments are in french :-/

[see the source](http://icareo.free.fr/ups/1966599653.cs)

**[edit]** In fact, I remember it was to scroll and scale a Panels background. But it shouldnt be so hard to modify for applying it to any object as the transformations are the same for images and elements.

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought that it might be useful to translate the canvas to the mouse location each time while zooming, thus giving the user the feeling he's zooming to the mouse cursor.

Comment: BTW, comments are in English, so don't worry about that :)